# How to place button on the botton in a TAB?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I want to put a button on the bottom of a TAB. But it is not working even I use `justify-self: end;` or `bottom: 0`

Html:

```
<mat-tab-group>
   <mat-tab label="First" class="container"><div>content 1</div>
       <button class="btn">Submit</button>
   </mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

CSS:

```
container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.btn {
   justify-self: end;
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efdyvz?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.css)

Comment: you can use` margin-top: auto; ` if this does not work then check your container height

Comment: @WaseemAlmoliky, I tried it before with `margin-top: auto;`. It is not working. You can test it in stackblitz.

Comment: It doesn't work even I set `height: 1000px;`

Comment: I've checked the stackblitz link I found that it's because container class is removed from the button parent.

Comment: @WaseemAlmoliky, it is there. in mat-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the stackblitz link I found that it's because container class is removed from the button parent you can make sure of that when you inspect it with dev tools.
this may be because of compilations.

a quick solution would be to wrap your button with another `div`.

check this code bellow.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <div class="container">
      <div>content 1</div>
      <button class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.btn {
  justify-self: end;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the space that you want use is a padding of the container `.basic-container`.

You can solve it using `margin-top` in your `.btn` with a specific value, ie: 20px.

If you want to use that space you have to change the padding to `30px 30px 0px 30px` this makes the container to have 30 px padding in all directions except for the bottom side

later in your container `.mat-tab-body-content` you have to set an specific `height`, I use `180px`.
I added flex styles too:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

And finally in your `.btn`, `margin-top: auto;`
If you don't like how your button looks like now you add `width: fit-content;`.

Comment: I don't want to set specific height. What I want the thing in the tab on the top, the button is closed to the very bottom. Somehow like the button in http://jsfiddle.net/s4bsaquq/

Comment: `You can solve it using margin-top in your .btn with a specific value, ie: 20px.`